# Extra Categories shown in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has the languages spoken in an Indian State (English, Hindi, Punjabi) as a categorical variable. 
But when I run to see the number of categories, it shows:

> Factor w/ 4 levels: "0", English, Hindi, Punjabi

Why am I getting "0"?

Comment: Can you past at least sample of your data with `dput()`? It seems that the specific column contains also empty entries (or with a value "0")

Comment: Why don't you use `which` to see what rows have that value?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to understand exactly what's going on without more information about your data or a sample.
Did you initialize the data as factors or it was loaded automatically so?

Here is what I would check:

1) Do you have any `null` data-points within this variable? Maybe they are are assigned '0'.

2) If your data originates from a csv type file, try reading the data without `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and only then convert the variable type.

3) From my experience, sometimes R behaves very strangely with any language that is not English (encoding in R is somewhat weak). Maybe the other languages have special characters that offsets the leves?

4) Try to query the factors that match to '0'. What are you getting?

Comment: It was loaded automatically as factor.

1. I checked. No Null points
2. read that way
4. I'll just try that

Answer (score 0):

A sample of your dataset would be helpful but generally to see (in an exhaustive way) all possible categories in your column you have to convert it first to character:

```
unique( as.character(df$column) )
```